# Altium: remove some layer

Tags: altium

I have several layer in my pcb design and some of those layers are unwanted as they seems to conflict with each other when i export gerber file.
How to remove some mechanical layer ?

Comment: When you generate the gerbres you can choose which layers to use. If you uncheck all unnecessary layers, you still have conflicts?

Comment: I want to remove them before generating the gerber file during the pcb design processes. I have imported a pcb file where there are too many mechanical layer, I want to remove some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting unwanted mechanical layers on the Gerbers, make sure that the 'add to all plot' options are unchecked in the [Gerber Setup](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/WorkspaceManager_Dlg-GerberSetup_Form%28%28Gerber+Setup%29%29_AD) dialog for the output job.

[image]

You can also hide, delete or delete all objects on a layer but there may be no compelling reason to do so if you just want the layer contents not to appear on the Gerbers.